# How to find files modified in last day, strip parameters from path and run a command on them daily with cron?

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

Say I have a list of files like these:

```
/my/dir/20/banner-35.jpg
/my/dir/18/poster-500.jpg
/my/dir/15/fanart-360.jpg
/my/dir/10/banner-70.jpg
(...)
```

I need to run a command like this on them:

`convert /my/dir/20/banner.jpg -resize x35 -unsharp 0x0.5+0.5+0.008 -quality 95 /my/dir/20/banner-35.jpg`

`convert /my/dir/18/poster.jpg -resize x500 -unsharp 0x0.5+0.5+0.008 -quality 95 /my/dir/18/banner-500.jpg`

However, I only want to do this for files that were modified in the past 24 hours. With some help I eventually go to this one:

`find /my/dir -type f -mtime -1 -name '*-*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'for path do dir=${path%/*} file=${path##*/} height=${file%.*}; convert "$dir/${file%-*}.jpg" -resize "x${height#*-}" -unsharp 0x0.5+0.5+0.008 -quality 95 "$path"; touch -r "$dir/${file%-*}.jpg" "$path"; done' _ {} +`

My first question is, how would you simplify this command, if possible?

Second one is actually the problem I'm having...

I need this command to run daily with cron and find files only modified in the last 24hours. But say I have some new files in `/my/dir` that were changed in the past 24hours; however, I have a power failure before the cron job could run and the computer only came up 2 days later. When the job runs again, it will look for files modified in the past 24 hours, and it will miss the files modified a few days ago because of the missed job(s).

I could increase `mtime` to more days for instance, but that is not a very good solution because every time the script runs, it will re-convert already converted files, which is pointless.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking of storing the result of find in a file, with a bash script you can loop through the entries for example(for entry in `cat findResult`)
and then execute your command this is much simpler. as for the power cut, may you want to rename the converted files by adding "converted" after treating every file in the loop.this way you can run find -name  '*-*.jpg' ! -name '*converted*'.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating files for this. And I need the files to be overwritten, that's the whole point.

Comment: i am writing a sample script, be back in 10

Comment: Please do not waste your time if it's not a one liner that runs standalone that I can add to cron. That's what I'm looking for. But I still appreciate the fact that you're trying to help.

Comment: ok, but aren't you mixing the input and the output in the convert command ? http://linux.die.net/man/1/convert
convert [input-options] input-file [output-options] output-file

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

find /my/dir -name '*-*.jpg' ! -name "*converted*" > /tmp/findResult

for entry in `cat /tmp/findResult`
do
   convert $entry -resize x35 -unsharp 0x0.5+0.5+0.008 -quality 95 `echo $entry | sed "s@-[0-9]\+@-converted@"` 
    rm $entry
done
rm /tmp/findResult
```

then you can add this script by issuing:

```
$ crontab -e 
 30 08 * * *  bash path_to_script
```

I was reading the convert manual and i saw that the input file must precede the output.

Comment: Like I said, this is not what I'm after. But thanks.